# How could I pass a value from one function to another function

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I want to pass the value of $ this->clienta to the info function,I get the value of null when I put the var_dump,I do it to be able to do a json since if I do it in index at the time of using json it also sends me the echo view

```
public function index($id_cliente)
{
    if (!isset($this->session->id_usuario)) {
        return redirect()->to(base_url());
    }

    $mascotas = $this->mascota->getList($id_cliente);
    $clientes = $this->mascota->getListaC($id_cliente);

    $data = [
        'titulo' => 'Mascotas', 'datos' => $mascotas, 'cliente' => $clientes,
        'idcliente' => $id_cliente,
    ];

    $this->clienta = $id_cliente;
    
    echo view('header');
    echo view('nav');
    echo view('mascotas/mascotas', $data);
    echo view('footer');

}

public function info()
{
    $r = $this->clienta;
    var_dump($r);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the issue, but if you call `info()` after you've called `index()` (and you're passing in something other than `null` to your `index()`-method), it shouldn't be null (at least not if you're working with the same class instance). If you call `info()` before you call `index()`, then `$this->clienta` won't be set (unless you set it else where as well?).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to pass `$id_cliente` value to `info()` because you are assigning `$this->clienta = $id_cliente;` here.

You will have to call the `info($id_cliente)` function inside your `index($id_cliente)` function and pass the value as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

send it to view then get it as get variable

```
public function index($id_cliente)
{
    if (!isset($this->session->id_usuario)) {
        return redirect()->to(base_url());
    }

    $mascotas = $this->mascota->getList($id_cliente);
    $clientes = $this->mascota->getListaC($id_cliente);

    $data = [
        'titulo' => 'Mascotas', 'datos' => $mascotas, 'cliente' => $clientes,
        'idcliente' => $id_cliente,
    ];

    $data['clienta'] = $id_cliente;
    
    echo view('header');
    echo view('nav');
    echo view('mascotas/mascotas', $data);
    echo view('footer');

}

public function info()
{
    echo $this->request->get('id');
    exit;
}
```

this is the only way